# jQuery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, siblings

**Our html:**

```
<ul class="accordion">
 <li>
  <h2 class="a-head">head 1</h2>
  <div class="a-body">body 1</div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <h2 class="a-head">head 2</h2>
  <div class="a-body">body 2</div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <h2 class="a-head">head 3</h2>
  <div class="a-body">body 3</div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".accordion .a-head").click(function()
{
    $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#ccc"}).next(".a-body").slideToggle().siblings(".a-body").slideUp();
    $(this).siblings().css({backgroundColor:"#fff"});
});
```

This accordion begins to work If I remove `<li></li>`. **How do I make it work with current code?**

Actually problem is in `.siblings()`.

Thanks.

Comment: Question title has no relation to actual question. I was this close to voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2Z5L/)  with your code and it seems to work just fine, with the `<li>`s in place.  I put in a 2nd `div` under "head 2" and *that* doesn't do what I'd expect, but that's not in your question.

Comment: @Stephen P there is no accordion effect

Comment: @Happy, you mean to tell me [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) doesn't exist?

Comment: @Happy - Oh! Of course! My brain obviously broke down. Yes, it slides the divs open/closed from the heading but doesn't close the other div when you click to open another one. Well, at least there's a fiddle for it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer you this:

#### jQuery:

```
$('li h2.a-head').click(
    function(){
        $(this).closest('ul').find('div.a-body').slideUp(400);
        $(this).closest('li').find('div.a-body').slideToggle(400);
    });
```

#### css:

```
li div.a-body {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/34tBE/).

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want? : http://jsfiddle.net/v2Z5L/1/
It could be simpler if you'd put a container for your "a-body" elements. For now, each of them slide, one by one.